# Eclipse can't find the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, troubleshooting, eclipse

I'm having problems getting Eclipse to start... It can't find the Java virtual machine. Based on suggestions online, I've tried adding...

```
; "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin"
```

to my Path variable, and also I've tried adding the following two lines...

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client/jvm.dll
```

to my eclipse.ini file. Neither seems to work yet.

The exact error message when I try and open eclipse is...

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available  
in order to run Eclipse. 
No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:  
C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH
```

I've verified that Java works, and that it's at the location I was expecting... Still no go.

Comment: You are mixing forward and backslashes above; that could be part of the problem.

Comment: those two things I tried separately... and I've tried flipping slashes... no go.

Comment: Can you run 'java' from command prompt?

Comment: Have you verified that javaw.exe is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin`?

Comment: Windows always uses backslashes "\" in path names

Comment: I've verified the location, running java without args gives me the normal argument descriptions, and java works when I go to http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp.  Also, in my experience, slashes tend to work both ways in windows shells

Answer (score 2):

The -vm argument should be your path to java.exe, or actually javaw.exe (javaw.exe doesn't have a DOS prompt hanging around).

```
-vm  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe"
```

Make sure the bitsize matches - you need to match the bitsize of your java (32 bit in your example) and Eclipse (needs to be 32 bit, but 64 bit is available).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized, after little over an hour, that I had a 32bit Java installed and had downloaded a 64bit version of Eclipse. 
Downloading a 32bit Eclipse fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if java is set in the system variable, if so then open command prompt and give command as java -help. It should give you java related help.
2. Go to windows -> preferences -> java --> check whether jre is set or selected in installed jres
3. Even try to set java in the build path.
4. Start with the eclipse with clean command.

Comment: `java -help` neither gives infos to env vars nor to Eclipse's launcher. "_Go to windows -> preferences -> java_" or "_set java in the build path_" is not possible when the issue is at starting Eclipse with its _Eclipse Launcher_ already. The `-clean` command just [cleans the workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030064/1744774) and doesn't solve any issues related to Eclipse's launcher.